# Issue with JQuery Drag inside a Frameset

Tags: jquery-ui-draggable

I have the following issue when we drag a div beyond a frame border. This can be noted in the URL below.

http://www33.brinkster.com/sacoe99/Frameset.htm

Following is the list of steps to simulate.

1. Drag the div with the heading "Add Information" towards the bottom frame
2. Do not release the mouse till the mouse crosses the bottom frame.
3. Once the mouse has been moved beyond the bottom frame, release the mouse.
4. Now without clicking (left mouse down), move the mouse back inside the frame.
5. We can notice that, even though the left click is not done, the drag is still happening.